# Reuse method defined under another XML in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, url-mapping, xml-configuration, struts2-namespace

Here are the sample two xmls.

`email.xml:`

```xml
<action name="mailSelect" class="com.my.EmailAction">
    <result name="success">mailSelect.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I want to use the same method call defined in email.xml in another xml.

`another.xml:`

```xml
<action name="mailSelect" class="com.my.EmailAction">
    <result name="success">/email/mailSelect.jsp</result>
</action>
```

When I tried to call, the action being called is `http://localhost:8080/test/web/another/mailSelect` instead of the correct `http://localhost:8080/test/web/email/mailSelect`.

Any way to reuse the same method in another xml?

Comment: Method? Do you mean action? Could you explain more what are you trying to do.

Comment: The action called depends on url you entered the browser, which of them you did?

Comment: As others have pointed out, your action is determined by the namespace and action name, if the invocation is identical how do you expect different results?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the action names don't clashes you should configure them in different namespaces.

```xml
<package name="email" namespace="/web/email" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="mailSelect" class="com.my.EmailAction">
    <result name="success">/email/mailSelect.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>

<package name="another" namespace="/web/another" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="mailSelect" class="com.my.EmailAction">
    <result name="success">mailSelect.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

---

For better understanding namespaces look at [Struts 2 Namespace configuration example and explanation](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-namespace-configuration-example-and-explanation/) tutorial.